# What are the foods that are low in fat but high in calories?

Tags: calories, weight-gain, fat

Can you cite the foods that are low in fat but high in calories?

I'm 21, male, around 5'7" tall and I'm kinda skinny. I've read online that one of the things I should consider to gain weight is taking in food which is low in fat and high in calories.

Comment: Pure nutrition type questions are off-topic as outlined in our [faq]. You are welcome to update the question and make it fit so long as it is within the scope defined in our faq.

Comment: Sad to see this question closed. NutritionData.Self.com has a [nutrient search engine](http://nutritiondata.self.com/tools/nutrient-search) that can search exactly by that: high nutrient1, low nutrient2. Here's a search for [foods highest in calories and lowest in fat](http://nutritiondata.self.com/foods-000001000000015000000.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, straight sugar is high in calories but low in fat. Its high in simple carbohydrates.

That said, I'm not sure the advice you read was so great. It likely comes from the outdated belief that dietary fat/cholesterol equals fat/cholesterol in your body. Eat too much of any of the 3 macronutrient categories (protein/fat/carbohydrate) and you will get fat. Eating huge amounts of *simple* carbohydrates and the associated sustained high blood glucose levels over a long period of time can put a strain on your pancreas and in some cases lead to diabetes, varying levels of insulin resistance, and [arterial plaque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atherosclerosis).

If you want to put on weight, you have to decide what kind of weight you want to put on. If you want to put on fat, the best way to do that is just to eat lots of food with little or no exercise. If you have a normal digestive system then there is always a point at which your body fails to burn all the calories you consume, and you put on fat. If you have a faster metabolism than average, this will be more food than others eat.

If you want to put on muscle, then you have to train hard in the gym whilst eating lots of quality food.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: I actually already eat a lot more than the others I eat with. As an example, whenever me and a co-worker eat out, I normally have 3 or 4 cups of rice (I live in the Philippines) and I would always wow them with how I can eat that much and not gain any noticeable weight. I'm also **not** an outgoing person so no problem with the little to no exercise. :/ Most of them say I'm lucky to have fast metabolism even without being physically active but I honestly don't feel at all lucky. I really want to put on weight, not even a buff body, just weight, so as not to be skinny for my age.

Comment: Your metabolism clearly seems to be able to handle carbohydrates really well (which you aren't happy with). Try indulging in more fats.